# Objective C UIButton with divider and changes textcolor when selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have created a row of `UIButtons` and added one week's date and day as `UILabel` on it. I have also created a `UIView` selector that when the button is selected, it will highlight the whole button.

Now I am stuck with how to add a separator or vertical lines between the buttons. And instead of highlighting the `UIButton` I wish to change the `text colour` to blue when the button is selected. Please help

What I have created

[image: what i have]

what i am trying to achieve

[image: want to achieve]

Code

```
CGFloat HEIGHT_BTN = 55.0; //--- 10 pixels from the navigation view

CGFloat HEIGHT_LABEL = 30.0;
CGFloat HEIGHT_LABEL2 = 15.0;


   -(void)setupSegmentButtons
{
    CGFloat Y_POS_BTN = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height+5;

//=== The view where the buttons sits
navigationView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,Y_POS_BTN,self.view.frame.size.width,HEIGHT_BTN)];
navigationView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

[self.view addSubview:navigationView]; //=== Create a View called navigationView

//==== Setup the shadows
UIBezierPath *shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.navigationView.bounds];
self.navigationView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
self.navigationView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
self.navigationView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5.0f, 5.0f);
self.navigationView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8f;
self.navigationView.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath;

//=== Get the dates and formatting of the dates
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *beginningOfThisWeek;
NSTimeInterval durationOfWeek;

[calendar rangeOfUnit:NSWeekCalendarUnit
            startDate:&beginningOfThisWeek
             interval:&durationOfWeek
              forDate:now];

NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:NSUIntegerMax fromDate:now];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YYYY"];
NSDateFormatter *datelblFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[datelblFormat setDateFormat:@"dd"];
NSDateFormatter *daylblFormat= [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[daylblFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE"];

//=== Loop 7 times to create the Buttons and the 2 lines Labels
for (int i = 0; i<numControllers; i++) {

    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i*(self.navigationView.frame.size.width/numControllers), 0, (self.navigationView.frame.size.width/numControllers),HEIGHT_BTN)];

    [navigationView addSubview:button]; //=== Put the buttons into the navigation View

    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[calendar dateFromComponents:comps]];
    [dtDate addObject:dateString];

    NSString *lblDate = [datelblFormat stringFromDate:[calendar dateFromComponents:comps]];

    firstLineButton = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,5,self.view.frame.size.width/numControllers,HEIGHT_LABEL)];

    firstLineButton.text = lblDate;
    firstLineButton.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
    firstLineButton.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    firstLineButton.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [button addSubview:firstLineButton]; //=== Put the Date in the 1st line of the the button

    NSString *lblDay = [daylblFormat stringFromDate:[calendar dateFromComponents:comps]];

    UILabel *secondLineButton = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,28,self.view.frame.size.width/numControllers,HEIGHT_LABEL2)];
    secondLineButton.text = lblDay;
    secondLineButton.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    secondLineButton.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11];
    secondLineButton.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [button addSubview:secondLineButton]; //=== Put the Day in the 2nd line of the Button

    button.tag = i; //--- IMPORTANT: if you make your own custom buttons, you have to tag them appropriately

    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:236.0f/255.0f green:0/255.0f blue:140.0f/255.0f alpha:0.6];//%%% buttoncolors

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(tapSegmentButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    ++comps.day;
}

[self setupSelector]; //=== The selection bar or highligthed area
}

//=== sets up the selection bar under the buttons or the highligted buttons on the navigation bar
-(void)setupSelector {

    //CGFloat Y_POS_BTN = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height+5;
    selectionBar = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, Y_BUFFER, (self.view.frame.size.width/numControllers),HEIGHT_BTN)];
    selectionBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:236.0f/255.0f green:0/255.0f blue:140.0f/255.0f alpha:0.6]; //%%% sbcolor
    //selectionBar.alpha = 0.8; //%%% sbalpha
    [navigationView addSubview:selectionBar];
}

//=== When the top button is tapped
#pragma mark Setup
 -(void)tapSegmentButtonAction:(UIButton *)button {

    sDtDate = dtDate[button.tag];

    [self LoadClasses];

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [weakSelf updateCurrentPageIndex:button.tag];

    NSInteger xCoor = selectionBar.frame.size.width*self.currentPageIndex;

    selectionBar.frame = CGRectMake(xCoor, selectionBar.frame.origin.y, selectionBar.frame.size.width, selectionBar.frame.size.height);
}
```

Comment: Why not use a UISegmentedControl?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'll prefer a more elegant way to achieve this.

First, create a `UIButton` subclass (let's say `WeekdayButton`) which will generate an attributed title from `NSDate` and configure so it is able to display a multiline title with different fonts.

> WeekdayButton.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WeekdayButton : UIButton

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *date;

@end
```

> WeekdayButton.m

```
#import "WeekdayButton.h"

@implementation WeekdayButton

static NSDateFormatter *dayFormatter;
static NSDateFormatter *weekFormatter;

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    [self setup];
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self setup];
}

- (void)setup {
    self.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    self.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    self.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:236.0f/255.0f green:0/255.0f blue:140.0f/255.0f alpha:0.6];
}


- (void)setDate:(NSDate *)date {
    _date = date;

    NSAttributedString *normalTitle = [self generateNormalTitle];;
    NSAttributedString *selectedTitle = [self generateSelectedTitle];

    [self setAttributedTitle:normalTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self setAttributedTitle:selectedTitle forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}

- (NSAttributedString *)generateNormalTitle {
    NSMutableAttributedString *result = [NSMutableAttributedString new];

    if (!dayFormatter) {
        dayFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
        dayFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd";
    }

    if (!weekFormatter) {
        weekFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
        weekFormatter.dateFormat = @"EEE";
    }

    NSString *day = [[dayFormatter stringFromDate:self.date] stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];
    NSString *week = [weekFormatter stringFromDate:self.date];

    [result appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:day
                                                                   attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20]}]];

    [result appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:week
                                                                   attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11]}]];

    [result addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor whiteColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, result.length)];

    return result;
}

- (NSAttributedString *)generateSelectedTitle {
    NSMutableAttributedString *result = [[self generateNormalTitle] mutableCopy];
    [result addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blueColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, result.length)];
    return result;
}

@end
```

Then in your ViewController make a horizontal `UIStackView`, generate 7 `WeekdayButton` button and pass `NSDate` object starting from today.

> ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "WeekdayButton.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIStackView *stackView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setupWeekDayButtons];
}

- (void)setupWeekDayButtons {

    UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, self.view.frame.size.width, 55)];
    containerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [self.view addSubview:containerView];

    containerView.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
    containerView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    containerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
    containerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 5);

    self.stackView = [[UIStackView alloc] initWithFrame:containerView.bounds];
    self.stackView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    self.stackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal;
    self.stackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistributionFill;
    self.stackView.spacing = 0;
    [containerView addSubview:self.stackView]; //Embeding stackview in a UIView cause UIStackView can't draw shadow.

    int numberOfDays = 7;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDays; i++) {
        NSDate *date = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:i * 24 * 3600];
        WeekdayButton *button = [WeekdayButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(weekDayTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.date = date;
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [self.stackView addArrangedSubview:button];
        [button.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.stackView.widthAnchor
                                         multiplier:1/(CGFloat)numberOfDays].active = YES;

        if (i != numberOfDays - 1) {
            UIView *separator = [UIView new];
            separator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            separator.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            [button addSubview:separator];

            [separator.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:1].active = true;
            [separator.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:button.trailingAnchor constant:0].active = YES;
            [separator.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:button.centerYAnchor constant:0].active = YES;
            [separator.heightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:button.heightAnchor multiplier:1 constant:-20].active = YES;
        }
    }
}

- (void)weekDayTapped:(WeekdayButton *)sender {
    [self.stackView.arrangedSubviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setSelected:) withObject:nil]; //Deselecting all buttons
    sender.selected = YES; 

    NSLog(@"Selected: %@", sender.date);
    //TODO: Do your logic after selection here
}

@end
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I here provide an answer with the power of stack view and auto layout

The code will be limited and you can customized almost everything in IB.
Tint color of buttons may needs care when setting selected state.

```
-(IBAction)selector:(id)sender{
    UIButton * button = (UIButton *)sender;
    [button setSelected:  !button.isSelected ];
 }
```

[setting in IB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6Nn9.png)

[selected State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmySn.png)

[topstackview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBqUl.png)
[second stack view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAVA3.png)

Use this idea, you can build your example much faster and safe.

Comment: Hi E.Coms, welcome to SO! Please be aware that the SO community frowns upon answers that are mostly images since it gravely reduces the discoverability of your answer. Images of Xcode setting dialogs are especially problematic since it does not highlight the _important_ setting. Please do consider replacing or augmenting those images with the critical bits of the answer. Thanks for contributing!

Answer (score 1):

For: "how to add a separator or vertical lines between the buttons":
After `[button addSubview:secondLineButton]; //=== Put the Day in the 2nd line of the Button` add a view as separator

```
if (i < (numControllers - 1)){  
    UIView *separator = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(button.frame.size.width - 1, 5, 1, button.frame.size.height - 10))];  
        separator.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor
        [button addSubview:separator];  
}
```

For text color, create: `btnCurrentSelected` and:

```
@interface YouClass : UIViewController
{
    UIButton *btnCurrentSelected;
}




 -(void)tapSegmentButtonAction:(UIButton *)button {

    sDtDate = dtDate[button.tag];

    [self LoadClasses];
    [btnCurrentSelected setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal] // set color for old button selected
    btnCurrentSelected = button
    [btnCurrentSelected setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal] // set color for button selected

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [weakSelf updateCurrentPageIndex:button.tag];

    NSInteger xCoor = selectionBar.frame.size.width*self.currentPageIndex;

    selectionBar.frame = CGRectMake(xCoor, selectionBar.frame.origin.y, selectionBar.frame.size.width, selectionBar.frame.size.height);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply How to create `btnCurrentSelected` ? And also how to not draw the last separator? I need only six separator?

Comment: not working. The title cooler is still the same whether it is selected or unselected.

Comment: the title color still remains the same. I am using UI label to create the title. Is there a way to change the label text color when selected?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use UIButton here, just need to customize a UIControl subclass where the needed customize layout inside, you need to handle highlighting Or general state inside the selected Set method